# Fluent Nhibernate mapping help

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Domain:

```
 public class Account
{

    public virtual int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string HostName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        PersonRoles = new List<PersonRole>();
    }
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PersonGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string SaltKey { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonType { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual int? AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonRole> PersonRoles { get; private set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
 public AccountMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.AccountId, "AccountId").Column("AccountId");
        Map(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.HostName);
        Map(x => x.CreatedOn);
        Map(x => x.Deleted);
        Table("crm_accounts");
    }

  public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PersonId).Column("PersonId");
        Map(x => x.PersonGuid);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.Surname);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x => x.SaltKey);
        Map(x => x.PersonType);
        Map(x => x.CreatedOn);
        Map(x => x.Deleted);
        Map(x => x.Active);

        HasManyToMany<PersonRole>(x => x.PersonRoles)
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("PersonId")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("crm_people_roles_mapping");

        //Map(x => x.AccountId);
        References(x => x.Account, "AccountId").Column("AccountId");
        Table("crm_people");
    }
```

Issue:

When saving a new person with an account id everything saves OK except for the acccount id field.

A person doesn't need to have an account to exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HNibernate doesn't know what to do with your AccountId. On your person object, you've got an Account and an AccountId property. I'll bet if you assigned the Account to the person before you save it, it'd all start working.

Get rid of that AccountId property. You don't need it.

Comment: When you say get rid of the AccountId property, do you mean in the domain? EDIT: Ah got it, thanks. Removed from domain and seems to be working.

Comment: Yes. You've already got an Account property and it has an Id. The Id on the root object is redundant and confusing.